# Voxel Islands - Dynamic mesh generation

Tags: c#, unity3d

While I can often understand the performance reasons behind using fixed-size arrays to store vertex, triangle and UV data, I've often found it annoying because it makes dynamically generating meshes somewhat difficult. In order to fix this, I've built a small helper class to make the process much easier. It currently only supports vertex, triangle and UV generation, but that's really all I need at the moment.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace VoxelIslands.Engine.Utilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is simply a wrapper used to dynamically generate mesh data for
    /// things like voxels and chunks. In the end, it will be converted to a normal
    /// Unity3D mesh.
    /// </summary>
    public class DynamicMesh
    {
        private List<Vector3> Vertices { get; set; }
        private List<int> Triangles { get; set; }
        private List<Vector2> UVs { get; set; }
        private List<Vector3> ColliderVertices { get; set; }
        private List<int> ColliderTriangles { get; set; }
        private Vector3 MeshOffset { get; set; }
        private bool _GenerateColliderData { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the DynamicMesh class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="meshOffset">The offset of the mesh and it's vertices.</param>
        /// <param name="generateColliderData">Whether or not to generate collider data.</param>
        public DynamicMesh(Vector3 meshOffset, bool generateColliderData = true)
        {
            this.Vertices = new List<Vector3>() { };
            this.Triangles = new List<int>() { };
            this.UVs = new List<Vector2>() { };
            this.ColliderVertices = new List<Vector3>() { };
            this.ColliderTriangles = new List<int>() { };
            this.MeshOffset = meshOffset;
            this._GenerateColliderData = generateColliderData;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function creates a new Unity3D mesh from the collider data contained in the vertex,
        /// and triangle data. The mesh returned by this function is intended to be used for collisions
        /// only.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A newly created collider mesh.</returns>
        public Mesh CreateColliderMesh()
        {
            Mesh colliderMesh = new Mesh();
            colliderMesh.vertices = this.ColliderVertices.ToArray();
            colliderMesh.triangles = this.ColliderTriangles.ToArray();
            colliderMesh.RecalculateNormals();
            return colliderMesh;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function creates a new Unity3D mesh from the data contained in the vertex, triangle
        /// and UV data. The mesh returned by this function is intended to be used for rendering only.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A newly created rendering mesh.</returns>
        public Mesh CreateRenderingMesh()
        {
            Mesh renderingMesh = new Mesh();
            renderingMesh.vertices = this.Vertices.ToArray();
            renderingMesh.triangles = this.Triangles.ToArray();
            renderingMesh.RecalculateNormals();
            renderingMesh.uv = this.UVs.ToArray();
            return renderingMesh;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a new UV coordinate to the UV data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="uvCoordinate"></param>
        public void AddUVs(Vector2[] uvCoordinates)
        {
            this.UVs.AddRange(uvCoordinates);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add two trianges to form a quad. This is based of the most recent vertex
        /// data and will not work if your vertex data is empty. Collision data is generated
        /// only if collision mesh generation is enabled. There is however an optional 
        /// parameter that allows for you to enable or disable collider generation on the fly.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="generateColliderData">Whether or not to generate collider data.</param>
        public void AddQuad(bool generateColliderData = true)
        {
            if(this.Vertices.Count >= 4)
            {
                // Generate the first renderable triangle.
                this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 4);
                this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 3);
                this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 2);

                // Generate the second renderable triangle.
                this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 4);
                this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 2);
                this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 1);

                if(this._GenerateColliderData && generateColliderData)
                {
                    // Generate the first collider triangle.
                    this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 4);
                    this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 3);
                    this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 2);

                    // Generate the second collider triangle.
                    this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 4);
                    this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 2);
                    this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Rendering vertex data must contain enough vertices to generate a quad.");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a vertex to the vertex data list. A collider vertex is generated only
        /// if collision mesh generation is enabled. There is however an optional 
        /// parameter that allows for you to enable or disable collider generation on the fly.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vertexPosition">The position of the vertex.</param>
        /// <param name="vertexOffset">The offset of the vertex.</param>
        /// <param name="generateColliderData">Whether or not to generate collider data.</param>
        public void AddVertex(Vector3 vertexPosition, Vector3 vertexOffset, bool generateColliderData = true)
        {
            this.Vertices.Add((vertexPosition - this.MeshOffset) + vertexOffset);

            if(this._GenerateColliderData && generateColliderData)
            {
                this.ColliderVertices.Add((vertexPosition - this.MeshOffset) + vertexOffset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything that can be improved here?

<sub>This post is part one of a series based off of the contents of [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/ShearOfDoom/Voxel-Islands/blob/master/Engine/Utilities/DynamicMesh.cs)</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see much refactoring there, mostly just a matter of taste.

There are a lot of `this`is - you can do without them, most of the time they are only code bloat.

I prefer inversing the condition in the `AddQuad` method to reduce nesting and remove the last `else`

```
if(this.Vertices.Count < 4)
{
    throw...
}
```

One of the properies begins with an `_` underscore, is there a reason for that?

As you don't expose any of them publicly I'd turn them to regular fields.

You don't need to use `{}` for creating empty lists this `new List<int>() { }` is the same as `new List<int>()`. You can also initialize them together with the declaration.

It might be a good idea to prefix boolean variables with *is* or *can* if it makes sense.

You don't need to always explitly specify the type. If you define a new variable inside a method etc. you can use the `var` keyword to not repeat yourself.

Example:

```
public class DynamicMesh
{
    private List<Vector3> _vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<int> _triangles = new List<int>();
    private List<Vector2> _uvs = new List<Vector2>();
    private List<Vector3> _colliderVertices = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<int> _colliderTriangles = new List<int>();
    private Vector3 _meshOffset;
    private bool _canGnerateColliderData;


    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for the DynamicMesh class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="meshOffset">The offset of the mesh and it's vertices.</param>
    /// <param name="generateColliderData">Whether or not to generate collider data.</param>
    public DynamicMesh(Vector3 meshOffset, bool canGenerateColliderData = true)
    {
        _meshOffset = meshOffset;
        _canGnerateColliderData = canGenerateColliderData;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function creates a new Unity3D mesh from the collider data contained in the vertex,
    /// and triangle data. The mesh returned by this function is intended to be used for collisions
    /// only.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A newly created collider mesh.</returns>
    public Mesh CreateColliderMesh()
    {
        // using object initializer
        var colliderMesh = new Mesh
        {
            vertices = _colliderVertices.ToArray(),
            triangles = _colliderTriangles.ToArray(),
        };
        colliderMesh.RecalculateNormals();
        return colliderMesh;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function creates a new Unity3D mesh from the data contained in the vertex, triangle
    /// and UV data. The mesh returned by this function is intended to be used for rendering only.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A newly created rendering mesh.</returns>
    public Mesh CreateRenderingMesh()
    {
        var renderingMesh = new Mesh
        {
            vertices = _vertices.ToArray(),
            triangles = _triangles.ToArray(),
            uv = _uvs.ToArray(),
        };
        renderingMesh.RecalculateNormals();
        return renderingMesh;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new UV coordinate to the UV data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uvCoordinate"></param>
    public void AddUVs(Vector2[] uvCoordinates)
    {
        _uvs.AddRange(uvCoordinates);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add two trianges to form a quad. This is based of the most recent vertex
    /// data and will not work if your vertex data is empty. Collision data is generated
    /// only if collision mesh generation is enabled. There is however an optional 
    /// parameter that allows for you to enable or disable collider generation on the fly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="generateColliderData">Whether or not to generate collider data.</param>
    public void AddQuad(bool canGenerateColliderData = true)
    {
        if (_vertices.Count < 4)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Rendering vertex data must contain enough vertices to generate a quad.");
        }

        // Generate the first renderable triangle.
        _triangles.Add(_vertices.Count - 4);
        _triangles.Add(_vertices.Count - 3);
        _triangles.Add(_vertices.Count - 2);

        // Generate the second renderable triangle.
        _triangles.Add(_vertices.Count - 4);
        _triangles.Add(_vertices.Count - 2);
        _triangles.Add(_vertices.Count - 1);

        if (_canGnerateColliderData && canGenerateColliderData)
        {
            // Generate the first collider triangle.
            _colliderTriangles.Add(_colliderVertices.Count - 4);
            _colliderTriangles.Add(_colliderVertices.Count - 3);
            _colliderTriangles.Add(_colliderVertices.Count - 2);

            // Generate the second collider triangle.
            _colliderTriangles.Add(_colliderVertices.Count - 4);
            _colliderTriangles.Add(_colliderVertices.Count - 2);
            _colliderTriangles.Add(_colliderVertices.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a vertex to the vertex data list. A collider vertex is generated only
    /// if collision mesh generation is enabled. There is however an optional 
    /// parameter that allows for you to enable or disable collider generation on the fly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vertexPosition">The position of the vertex.</param>
    /// <param name="vertexOffset">The offset of the vertex.</param>
    /// <param name="generateColliderData">Whether or not to generate collider data.</param>
    public void AddVertex(Vector3 vertexPosition, Vector3 vertexOffset, bool canGenerateColliderData = true)
    {
        // perform calculation only once, then add its result whereever needed
        var vertexWithOffset = (vertexPosition - _meshOffset) + vertexOffset;

        _vertices.Add(vertexWithOffset);

        if (_canGnerateColliderData && canGenerateColliderData)
        {
            _colliderVertices.Add(vertexWithOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The logical duplication here is both tedious and potentially error-prone:

> ```
> // Generate the first renderable triangle.
> this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 4);
> this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 3);
> this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 2);
>
> // Generate the second renderable triangle.
> this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 4);
> this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 2);
> this.Triangles.Add(this.Vertices.Count - 1);
>
> if(this._GenerateColliderData && generateColliderData)
> {
>     // Generate the first collider triangle.
>     this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 4);
>     this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 3);
>     this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 2);
>
>     // Generate the second collider triangle.
>     this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 4);
>     this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 2);
>     this.ColliderTriangles.Add(this.ColliderVertices.Count - 1);
> }
> ```

I suggest to remedy with helper methods:

```
private void AddFirstTriangle(List<int> triangles, int base)
{
    triangles.Add(base - 4);
    triangles.Add(base - 3);
    triangles.Add(base - 2);
}

private void AddSecondTriangle(List<int> triangles, int base)
{
    triangles.Add(base - 4);
    triangles.Add(base - 2);
    triangles.Add(base - 1);
}
```

Which will simplify the original code to:

```
AddFirstTriangle(Triangles, Vertices.Count);
AddSecondTriangle(Triangles, Vertices.Count);

if(this._GenerateColliderData && generateColliderData)
{
    AddFirstTriangle(ColliderTriangles, ColliderVertices.Count);
    AddSecondTriangle(ColliderTriangles, ColliderVertices.Count);
}
```

You could go one step further with another helper method:

```
private void AddTriangles(List<int> triangles, int base)
{
    AddFirstTriangle(triangles, base);
    AddSecondTriangle(triangles, base);
}
```