# Voxel Islands - Level terrain generation

Tags: c#, game, unity3d

In Voxel Islands, each individual voxel is represented by their own unique class. Each of those unique classes is a subclass of a parent, `Voxel` class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using VoxelIslands.Engine.Utilities;

namespace VoxelIslands.Engine
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class represents a voxel in the world, and stores the specific data related
    /// to said voxel, like type, UV coordinates, mesh behaviours, etc.
    /// </summary>
    public class Voxel
    {
        public enum VoxelFaceDirection
        {
            North = 0,
            South = 1,
            East = 2,
            West = 3,
            Up = 4,
            Down = 5
        }

        public enum VoxelType : byte
        {
            Invalid = 255,
            Empty = 254,

            Stone = 0,
            Dirt = 1,
            Grass = 2,
            Wood = 3,
            Leaves = 4,
            Sand = 5,
            Slab = 6,
            Plank = 7,
            Pole = 8,
            Glass = 9,
            Timber = 10,

            Explosive = 251,
            Water = 252,
            Cloud = 253
        }

        public bool OverrideFaceGenerationRules { get; set; }
        public bool IsCollideable { get; set; }
        public Vector3 Offset { get; set; }
        public Vector3 HalvedOffset { get; set; }
        public VoxelType Type { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the Voxel class.
        /// </summary>
        public Voxel(bool overrideFaceGenerationRules, bool isCollideable, Vector3 offset, Vector3 halvedOffset, VoxelType type)
        {
            this.OverrideFaceGenerationRules = overrideFaceGenerationRules;
            this.IsCollideable = isCollideable;
            this.Offset = offset;
            this.HalvedOffset = halvedOffset;
            this.Type = type;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check to see whether a specific voxel face is solid or not.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="faceDirection">The direction the face is facing.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether or not the face is solid.</returns>
        public virtual bool IsFaceSolid(VoxelFaceDirection faceDirection)
        {
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function is responsible for generating the different face data associated with the
        /// voxel. This function can be overriden to allow for a variety of different face combonations.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parentlevel">The voxel's parent level.</param>
        /// <param name="currentMeshData">The level's current mesh data.</param>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the voxel.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate of the voxel.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The z coordinate of the voxel.</param>
        /// <returns>An updated level mesh.</returns>
        public virtual DynamicMesh CreateMeshFaces(Level parentlevel, DynamicMesh currentMeshData, int x, int y, int z)
        {
            // Generate the northern face of the voxel.
            if(!parentlevel.FetchVoxel(x, y, z + 1).IsFaceSolid(VoxelFaceDirection.South) || this.OverrideFaceGenerationRules)
            {
                currentMeshData = this.CreateNorthFace(currentMeshData, x, y, z);
            }

            // Generate the southern face of the voxel.
            if(!parentlevel.FetchVoxel(x, y, z - 1).IsFaceSolid(VoxelFaceDirection.North) || this.OverrideFaceGenerationRules)
            {
                currentMeshData = this.CreateSouthFace(currentMeshData, x, y, z);
            }

            // Generate the eastern face of the voxel.
            if(!parentlevel.FetchVoxel(x + 1, y, z).IsFaceSolid(VoxelFaceDirection.West) || this.OverrideFaceGenerationRules)
            {
                currentMeshData = this.CreateEastFace(currentMeshData, x, y, z);
            }

            // Generate the western face of the voxel.
            if(!parentlevel.FetchVoxel(x - 1, y, z).IsFaceSolid(VoxelFaceDirection.East) || this.OverrideFaceGenerationRules)
            {
                currentMeshData = this.CreateWestFace(currentMeshData, x, y, z);
            }

            // Generate the upwards face of the voxel.
            if(!parentlevel.FetchVoxel(x, y + 1, z).IsFaceSolid(VoxelFaceDirection.Down) || this.OverrideFaceGenerationRules)
            {
                currentMeshData = this.CreateUpwardsFace(currentMeshData, x, y, z);
            }

            // Generate the downwards face of the voxel.
            if(!parentlevel.FetchVoxel(x, y - 1, z).IsFaceSolid(VoxelFaceDirection.Up) || this.OverrideFaceGenerationRules)
            {
                currentMeshData = this.CreateDownwardsFace(currentMeshData, x, y, z);
            }

            return currentMeshData;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate UV coordinate data for a specific face on the voxel.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="faceDirection">The direction that the face is facing.</param>
        protected virtual Vector2[] GenerateUVs(VoxelFaceDirection faceDirection)
        {
            Vector2[] UVs = new Vector2[4];
            UVs[0] = new UVTile(3, 0).UVTileToUVCoordinate(UVTile.UVTileCorner.BottomLeft);
            UVs[1] = new UVTile(3, 1).UVTileToUVCoordinate(UVTile.UVTileCorner.TopLeft);
            UVs[2] = new UVTile(4, 1).UVTileToUVCoordinate(UVTile.UVTileCorner.TopRight);
            UVs[3] = new UVTile(4, 0).UVTileToUVCoordinate(UVTile.UVTileCorner.BottomRight);
            return UVs;
        }

        protected virtual DynamicMesh CreateNorthFace(DynamicMesh currentMeshData, int x, int y, int z)
        {
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddQuad(this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddUVs(this.GenerateUVs(VoxelFaceDirection.North));
            return currentMeshData;
        }

        protected virtual DynamicMesh CreateSouthFace(DynamicMesh currentMeshData, int x, int y, int z)
        {
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddQuad(this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddUVs(this.GenerateUVs(VoxelFaceDirection.South));
            return currentMeshData;
        }

        protected virtual DynamicMesh CreateEastFace(DynamicMesh currentMeshData, int x, int y, int z)
        {
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddQuad(this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddUVs(this.GenerateUVs(VoxelFaceDirection.East));
            return currentMeshData;
        }

        protected virtual DynamicMesh CreateWestFace(DynamicMesh currentMeshData, int x, int y, int z)
        {
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddQuad(this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddUVs(this.GenerateUVs(VoxelFaceDirection.West));
            return currentMeshData;
        }

        protected virtual DynamicMesh CreateUpwardsFace(DynamicMesh currentMeshData, int x, int y, int z)
        {
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y + this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddQuad(this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddUVs(this.GenerateUVs(VoxelFaceDirection.Up));
            return currentMeshData;
        }

        protected virtual DynamicMesh CreateDownwardsFace(DynamicMesh currentMeshData, int x, int y, int z)
        {
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z - this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x + this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddVertex(new Vector3(x - this.HalvedOffset.x, y - this.HalvedOffset.y, z + this.HalvedOffset.z), this.Offset, this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddQuad(this.IsCollideable);
            currentMeshData.AddUVs(this.GenerateUVs(VoxelFaceDirection.Down));
            return currentMeshData;
        }
    }
}
```

The next class, `Level`, is responsible for a variety of things. It will generate the initial level terrain (comprised of floating islands), which is done in the following steps:

1. Generate three perlin noise values, and perform linear interpolation between the first two using the third as the "time" value to produce a height value.
2. Iterate upwards for a certain distance based on the resulting height value and a height multiplier, and fill each coordinate with a solid voxel.
3. Iterate downwards for a certain distance based on the resulting height value and a different height multiplier and fill each coordinate with a solid voxel.
4. Determine whether certain features like rocks, trees and caves should be generated.

Here are some examples of what the terrain generator produces:

[image]

[image]

The level class is also responsible for updating the terrain based on player actions, like setting/destroying voxels, and a few other minor things.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using VoxelIslands.Engine.Utilities;
using VoxelIslands.Engine.Voxels;
using VoxelIslands.Utilities;

namespace VoxelIslands.Engine
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is intended to represent a "level" or island in the world. This class
    /// is responsible for generating, updating, and managing terrain in a "level".
    /// </summary>
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]
    public class Level : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public bool UseUniqueSeed = true;

        public int Width = 128;
        public int Height = 256;
        public int Depth = 128;

        public int ChunkWidth = 16;
        public int ChunkHeight = 16;
        public int ChunkDepth = 16;
        public bool UseLevelSizeStorage = true;

        public bool GenerateCaves = true;
        public float CaveGenerationChance = 20.0f;
        public int MinimumCaveRadius = 1;
        public int MaximumCaveRadius = 3;
        public int MinimumCaveLength = 10;
        public int MaximumCaveLength = 25;

        public bool GenerateClouds = false;
        public float CloudFrequency = 50.0f;
        public float CloudSolidityThreshold = 0.5f;
        public int BaseCloudHeight = 64;
        public int CloudThickness = 2;

        public float TerrainFrequencyOne = 20.0f;
        public float TerrainFrequencyTwo = 40.0f;
        public float TerrainFrequencyThree = 60.0f;
        public float FalloffCurveAMultiplier = 3;
        public float FalloffCurveBMultiplier = 2.25f;
        public float TopHeightMultiplier = 3.0f;
        public float BottomHeightMultiplier = 6.0f;
        public float DirtGenerationChance = 35.0f;
        public float DirtThreshold = 1.2f;
        public float RandomDirtThreshold = 0.15f;
        public float SolidityThreshold = 0.45f;

        public float TreeGenerationChance = 5.0f;
        public int MinimumTrunkHeight = 7;
        public int MaximumTrunkHeight = 10;
        public int MinimumLeavesRadius = 1;
        public int MaximumLeavesRadius = 3;
        public float BoulderGenerationChance = 1.0f;

        public int BaseIslandHeight = 64;
        public int BaseColumnHeightMultiplier = 10;

        public bool UsesPlayer = true;
        public GameObject EmptyChunkPrefab;

        private int WidthInChunks;
        private int HeightInChunks;
        private int DepthInChunks;

        public GameObject VoxelDestructionParticleSystem;

        public Voxel[,,] Voxels;
        public GameObject[,,] Chunks;
        public Vector3 PlayerSpawnPosition;

        private int _Seed;

        /// <summary>
        /// This function will update the chunk that resides at the chunk indexes of
        /// x, y and z. This function is intended for use in things like voxel placement,
        /// where multiple chunk updates may need to occur. If the supplied coordinates
        /// are out of bounds, this function will simply do nothing.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the chunk.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate of the chunk.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The z coordinate of the chunk.</param>
        public void UpdateChunk(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            if(
                x >= 0 && x < this.WidthInChunks &&
                y >= 0 && y < this.HeightInChunks &&
                z >= 0 && z < this.DepthInChunks
            )
            {
                // Grab the chunk object, it's mesh filter and collider, and create an empty
                // DynamicMesh which represents the chunk's updated mesh.
                GameObject chunkObject = this.Chunks[x, y, z];
                MeshFilter chunkMeshFilter = chunkObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
                MeshCollider chunkMeshCollider = chunkObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
                DynamicMesh newChunkMesh = new DynamicMesh(
                    new Vector3(x * this.ChunkWidth, y * this.ChunkHeight, z * this.ChunkDepth)
                );

                // Re-generate the chunk based on the new voxel data.
                for(int currentX = x * this.ChunkWidth; currentX < (x * this.ChunkWidth) + this.ChunkWidth; currentX++)
                {
                    for(int currentY = y * this.ChunkHeight; currentY < (y * this.ChunkHeight) + this.ChunkHeight; currentY++)
                    {
                        for(int currentZ = z * this.ChunkDepth; currentZ < (z * this.ChunkDepth) + this.ChunkDepth; currentZ++)
                        {
                            newChunkMesh = this.Voxels[currentX, currentY, currentZ].CreateMeshFaces(
                                this,
                                newChunkMesh,
                                currentX,
                                currentY,
                                currentZ
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Update the mesh and mesh collider of the chunk.
                chunkMeshFilter.mesh = newChunkMesh.CreateRenderingMesh();
                chunkMeshCollider.sharedMesh = null;
                chunkMeshCollider.sharedMesh = newChunkMesh.CreateColliderMesh();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function will perform a simple check to determine whether or not a
        /// set of provided coordinates are valid or not.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The z coordinate.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether or not the coordinate is valid.</returns>
        public bool IsValidCoordinate(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            return (
                x >= 0 && x < this.Width &&
                y >= 0 && y < this.Height &&
                z >= 0 && z < this.Depth
            );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function will "generate" an explosion with a certain radius and
        /// will visual display terrain destruction using particles.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x origin of the explosion.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y origin of the explosion.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The z origin of the explosion.</param>
        /// <param name="explosionRadius">The radius of the explosion.</param>
        /// <param name="updateRadius">The radius of which chunks to update.</param>
        public void GenerateExplosion(int x, int y, int z, int explosionRadius, int updateRadius)
        {
            List<Vector3> chunksToUpdate = new List<Vector3>() { };

            for(int currentX = x - explosionRadius; currentX <= x + explosionRadius; currentX++)
            {
                for(int currentY = y - explosionRadius; currentY <= y + explosionRadius; currentY++)
                {
                    for(int currentZ = z - explosionRadius; currentZ <= z + explosionRadius; currentZ++)
                    {
                        Vector3 edgeDistance = new Vector3(x + explosionRadius, y + explosionRadius, z + explosionRadius);
                        Vector3 origin = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                        Vector3 currentPosition = new Vector3(currentX, currentY, currentZ);

                        if(Random.Range(0, Vector3.Distance(origin, edgeDistance) / 2.0f) >= Vector3.Distance(origin, currentPosition))
                        {
                            if(this.IsValidCoordinate(currentX, currentY, currentZ))
                            {
                                if(
                                    Random.Range(0.0f, 100.0f) <= 20.0f && 
                                    this.Voxels[currentX, currentY, currentZ].Type != Voxel.VoxelType.Empty
                                )
                                {
                                    GameObject destructionParticles = (GameObject)Instantiate(
                                        this.VoxelDestructionParticleSystem,
                                        new Vector3(currentX, currentY, currentZ),
                                        Quaternion.identity
                                    );

                                    if((int)this.Voxels[currentX, currentY, currentZ].Type < ResourceManager.StaticVoxelSprites.Length)
                                    {
                                        destructionParticles.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = ResourceManager.StaticVoxelSprites[
                                            (int)this.Voxels[currentX, currentY, currentZ].Type
                                        ].texture;
                                    }
                                }

                                this.Voxels[currentX, currentY, currentZ] = new Empty();

                                int chunkX = (int)(System.Math.Floor((float)x / (float)this.ChunkWidth) * (float)this.ChunkWidth);
                                int chunkY = (int)(System.Math.Floor((float)y / (float)this.ChunkHeight) * (float)this.ChunkHeight);
                                int chunkZ = (int)(System.Math.Floor((float)z / (float)this.ChunkDepth) * this.ChunkDepth);

                                if(
                                    !chunksToUpdate.Contains(
                                        new Vector3(
                                            chunkX / this.ChunkWidth, 
                                            chunkY / this.ChunkHeight,
                                            chunkZ / this.ChunkDepth
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                                {
                                    chunksToUpdate.Add(
                                        new Vector3(
                                            chunkX / this.ChunkWidth, 
                                            chunkY / this.ChunkHeight,
                                            chunkZ / this.ChunkDepth
                                        )
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < chunksToUpdate.Count; i++)
            {
                int chunkX = (int)chunksToUpdate[i].x;
                int chunkY = (int)chunksToUpdate[i].y;
                int chunkZ = (int)chunksToUpdate[i].z;

                this.UpdateChunk(chunkX, chunkY, chunkZ);

                for(int newChunkX = -updateRadius; newChunkX < updateRadius; newChunkX++)
                {
                    for(int newChunkY = -updateRadius; newChunkY < updateRadius; newChunkY++)
                    {
                        for(int newChunkZ = -updateRadius; newChunkZ < updateRadius; newChunkZ++)
                        {
                            if(
                                (newChunkX != -updateRadius || newChunkX != updateRadius) &&
                                (newChunkY != -updateRadius || newChunkY != updateRadius) &&
                                (newChunkZ != -updateRadius || newChunkZ != updateRadius)
                            )
                            {
                                this.UpdateChunk(chunkX + newChunkX, chunkY + newChunkY, chunkZ + newChunkZ);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function will recursively generate a cave until it has finished,
        /// given the that the required conditions have been fufilled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The current x coordinate of the cave.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The current y coordinate of the cave.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The current z coordinate of the cave.</param>
        /// <param name="caveLength">The current length of the cave.</param>
        public void GenerateCave(int x, int y, int z, float caveLength)
        {
            if(caveLength > 0)
            {
                caveLength -= 1;

                int caveAreaRadius = Random.Range(this.MinimumCaveRadius, this.MaximumCaveRadius);

                // Fill the specified cave area with empty voxels, or the provided fill voxel.
                // which will create the cave section.
                for(int emptyX = x - caveAreaRadius; emptyX < x + caveAreaRadius + 1; emptyX++)
                {
                    for(int emptyY = y - caveAreaRadius; emptyY < y + caveAreaRadius + 1; emptyY++)
                    {
                        for(int emptyZ = z - caveAreaRadius; emptyZ < z + caveAreaRadius + 1; emptyZ++)
                        {
                            if(this.IsValidCoordinate(emptyX, emptyY, emptyZ))
                            {
                                this.Voxels[emptyX, emptyY, emptyZ] = new Empty();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Generate a new random direction which determines the direction that the cave will
                // "move" in to create new areas.
                Vector3 newRandomDirection = new Vector3(
                    Random.Range(-2, 2),
                    Random.Range(-2, 2),
                    Random.Range(-2, 2)
                );

                this.GenerateCave(
                    x + (int)newRandomDirection.x, 
                    y + (int)newRandomDirection.y, 
                    z + (int)newRandomDirection.z, 
                    caveLength
                );
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function will set a voxel based on the provided positions, and then
        /// recalculate the mesh of the chunk that the voxel resides in once the voxel
        /// data has been updated. This function will simply do nothing if the provided
        /// coordinates reside outside of the voxel array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="voxelType">The type of voxel to set.</param>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the voxel.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate of the voxel.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The z coordinate of the voxel.</param>
        /// <param name="setMode">The voxel setting mode. True is normal, and false is destruction.</param>
        public void SetVoxel(Voxel voxelType, int x, int y, int z, bool setMode = true)
        {
            if(this.IsValidCoordinate(x, y, z))
            {
                // Round the inputted coordinates to match the position of the chunk we
                // want to update.
                int chunkX = (int)(System.Math.Floor((float)x / (float)this.ChunkWidth) * (float)this.ChunkWidth);
                int chunkY = (int)(System.Math.Floor((float)y / (float)this.ChunkHeight) * (float)this.ChunkHeight);
                int chunkZ = (int)(System.Math.Floor((float)z / (float)this.ChunkDepth) * (float)this.ChunkDepth);

                // Set the provided coordinates to the provided voxel, if the setMode is
                // true, otherwise, set the provided voxel, and spawn a particle system
                // similar to that of the previous voxel.
                if(setMode)
                {
                    this.Voxels[x, y, z] = voxelType;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Create a new destruction-based particle system that will visual
                    // indicate the destruction of the voxel.
                    GameObject newDestructionParticleSystem = (GameObject)Instantiate(
                        this.VoxelDestructionParticleSystem,
                        new Vector3(x, y, z),
                        Quaternion.identity
                    );

                    // Set the texture of the newly created particle system to the
                    // corresponding texture. If a texture cannot be found, then
                    // the default particles are used.
                    if((int)this.Voxels[x, y, z].Type < ResourceManager.StaticVoxelSprites.Length)
                    {
                        newDestructionParticleSystem.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = ResourceManager.StaticVoxelSprites[
                            (int)this.Voxels[x, y, z].Type
                        ].texture;
                    }

                    this.Voxels[x, y, z] = new Empty();
                }

                this.UpdateChunk(chunkX / this.ChunkWidth, chunkY / this.ChunkHeight, chunkZ / this.ChunkDepth);

                // If the voxel's position is along a chunk x border, then update the
                // mesh of the neighboring chunk to prevent strange mesh issues.
                if(x == chunkX)
                {
                    this.UpdateChunk((chunkX / this.ChunkWidth) - 1, chunkY / this.ChunkHeight, chunkZ / this.ChunkDepth);
                }
                else if(x == chunkX + this.ChunkWidth - 1)
                {
                    this.UpdateChunk((chunkX / this.ChunkWidth) + 1, chunkY / this.ChunkHeight, chunkZ / this.ChunkDepth);
                }

                // If the voxel's position is along a chunk y border, then update the
                // mesh of the below chunk to prevent strange mesh issues.
                if(y == chunkY)
                {
                    this.UpdateChunk(chunkX / this.ChunkWidth, (chunkY / this.ChunkHeight) - 1, chunkZ / this.ChunkDepth);
                }
                else if(y == chunkY + this.ChunkHeight - 1)
                {
                    this.UpdateChunk(chunkX / this.ChunkWidth, (chunkY / this.ChunkHeight) + 1, chunkZ / this.ChunkDepth);
                }

                // If the voxel's position is along a chunk z border, then update the
                // mesh of the neighboring chunk to prevent strange mesh issues.
                if(z == chunkZ)
                {
                    this.UpdateChunk(chunkX / this.ChunkWidth, chunkY / this.ChunkHeight, (chunkZ / this.ChunkDepth) - 1);
                }
                else if(z == chunkZ + this.ChunkDepth - 1)
                {
                    this.UpdateChunk(chunkX / this.ChunkWidth, chunkY / this.ChunkHeight, (chunkZ / this.ChunkDepth) + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fetch a voxel based on the provided coordinates. If the provided coordinates are out of range,
        /// then an empty voxel is returned. This will force edge voxels to render their faces.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the voxel.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate of the voxel.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The z coordinate of the voxel.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Voxel FetchVoxel(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            if(this.IsValidCoordinate(x, y, z))
            {
                return this.Voxels[x, y, z];
            }
            else
            {
                return new Empty();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fill the chunk data with newly generated GameObject representations of chunks, each
        /// with their own custom mesh based on where they're positioned.
        /// </summary>
        public void GenerateChunkData()
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < this.WidthInChunks; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < this.HeightInChunks; y++)
                {
                    for(int z = 0; z < this.DepthInChunks; z++)
                    {
                        // Create a new, empty chunk object prefab which will represent the chunk itself
                        // in the world.
                        GameObject chunkObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(
                            this.EmptyChunkPrefab,
                            new Vector3(x * this.ChunkWidth, y * this.ChunkHeight, z * this.ChunkDepth),
                            Quaternion.identity
                        );

                        // Set the chunk's parent and name. This will help keep the heirarchy from getting
                        // cluttered with "Chunk Prefab (Clone)"s and will allow us to minimize the chunks.
                        chunkObject.transform.parent = this.transform;
                        chunkObject.name = string.Format("chunk_{0}_{1}_{2}", x, y, z);

                        // Grab the chunk object's mesh filter and collider, and create a new DynamicMesh
                        // which will represent the mesh of the chunk.
                        MeshFilter chunkObjectMeshFilter = chunkObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
                        MeshCollider chunkObjectMeshCollider = chunkObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
                        DynamicMesh chunkObjectMesh = new DynamicMesh(
                            new Vector3(x * this.ChunkWidth, y * this.ChunkHeight, z * this.ChunkDepth)
                        );

                        // Set the chunk's starting position.
                        int voxelXStart = x * this.ChunkWidth;
                        int voxelYStart = y * this.ChunkHeight;
                        int voxelZStart = z * this.ChunkDepth;

                        // Iterate over a range of values which lie inside the chunk's bound,
                        // and generate the chunk's mesh accordingly.
                        for(int voxelX = voxelXStart; voxelX < voxelXStart + this.ChunkWidth; voxelX++)
                        {
                            for(int voxelY = voxelYStart; voxelY < voxelYStart + this.ChunkHeight; voxelY++)
                            {
                                for(int voxelZ = voxelZStart; voxelZ < voxelZStart + this.ChunkDepth; voxelZ++)
                                {
                                    chunkObjectMesh = this.Voxels[voxelX, voxelY, voxelZ].CreateMeshFaces(
                                        this,
                                        chunkObjectMesh,
                                        voxelX,
                                        voxelY,
                                        voxelZ
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Set the mesh and mesh collider of the chunk object to the newly
                        // generated mesh and mesh colliders.
                        chunkObjectMeshFilter.mesh = chunkObjectMesh.CreateRenderingMesh();
                        chunkObjectMeshCollider.sharedMesh = null;
                        chunkObjectMeshCollider.sharedMesh = chunkObjectMesh.CreateColliderMesh();

                        // Add the chunk to the chunk array.
                        this.Chunks[x, y, z] = chunkObject;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fill the voxel array with procedurally generated voxel data based on what method of generation
        /// is used and the generation parameters provided. This method will do an "initialization fill"
        /// which fills the voxel array with empty voxels.
        /// </summary>
        public void GenerateVoxelData()
        {
            bool playerSpawnCreated = false;

            // Perform an initial "sweep" of the data and fill it with empty voxels.
            // This prevents NREs if we were to try and access an index with nothing in it.
            for(int x = 0; x < this.Width; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < this.Height; y++)
                {
                    for(int z = 0; z < this.Depth; z++)
                    {
                        this.Voxels[x, y, z] = new Empty();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Iterate across the level's x and z width ranges and begin to generate the
            // actual terrain.
            for(int x = 0; x < this.Width; x++)
            {
                for(int z = 0; z < this.Depth; z++)
                {
                    // Generate the first perlin noise result. This value is used as the first
                    // value in the noise lerp.
                    float perlinNoiseResultOne = Mathf.PerlinNoise(
                        (x + this._Seed) / this.TerrainFrequencyOne,
                        (z + this._Seed) / this.TerrainFrequencyOne
                    );

                    // Generate the second perlin noise result. This value is used as the second
                    // value in the noise lerp.
                    float perlinNoiseResultTwo = Mathf.PerlinNoise(
                        (x + this._Seed) / this.TerrainFrequencyTwo,
                        (z + this._Seed) / this.TerrainFrequencyTwo
                    );

                    // Generate the third perlin noise result. This value is used as the "time" 
                    // value in the noise lerp.
                    float perlinNoiseResultThree = Mathf.PerlinNoise(
                        (x + this._Seed) / this.TerrainFrequencyThree,
                        (z + this._Seed) / this.TerrainFrequencyThree
                    );

                    // Generate the final noise result, which is a lerp between the first and second
                    // noise results based on the third noise result.
                    float finalNoiseResult = Mathf.Lerp(
                        perlinNoiseResultOne,
                        perlinNoiseResultTwo,
                        perlinNoiseResultThree
                    ) - UtilityFunctions.GenerateFalloffValue(this.Width, x, z, this.FalloffCurveAMultiplier, this.FalloffCurveBMultiplier);

                    // Generate a terrain column if the perlin noise result meets the requirements
                    // for the solidity threshold.
                    if(finalNoiseResult >= this.SolidityThreshold)
                    {
                        bool treeGenerated = false;

                        int baseColumnHeight = (int)(
                            ((finalNoiseResult - this.SolidityThreshold) * this.BaseColumnHeightMultiplier) +
                            this.BaseIslandHeight
                        );
                        int topColumnHeight = (int)((finalNoiseResult - this.SolidityThreshold) * this.TopHeightMultiplier);
                        int bottomColumnHeight = (int)((finalNoiseResult - this.SolidityThreshold) * this.BottomHeightMultiplier);

                        // Generate a grass voxel at the base island height if the top column height
                        // is equal to zero. If the top column height is greater than zero, then a
                        // dirt voxel is generated.
                        if(topColumnHeight <= 0)
                        {
                            this.Voxels[x, baseColumnHeight, z] = new Sand();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.Voxels[x, baseColumnHeight, z] = new Dirt();
                        }

                        // Generate the top column based on the generated height. This will generate
                        // dirt until it hits the very last value in the top column.
                        for(int y = baseColumnHeight + 1; y < (baseColumnHeight + 1) + topColumnHeight; y++)
                        {
                            if(y >= 0 && y < this.Height)
                            {
                                // Generate a grass voxel, if the current y value is at the last value
                                // in the top column. If not, then dirt is generated.
                                if(((baseColumnHeight + 1) + topColumnHeight) - y == 1)
                                {
                                    this.Voxels[x, y, z] = new Grass();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    this.Voxels[x, y, z] = new Dirt();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Generate the bottom column based on the generated height. This will generate
                        // a mix of dirt and stone, with the occurence of stone becoming more likely the
                        // farther down the column is.
                        for(int y = baseColumnHeight - 1; y > (baseColumnHeight - 1) - bottomColumnHeight; y--)
                        {
                            if(y >= 0 && y < this.Height)
                            {
                                // If the current y value is greater than the dirt threshold then a dirt
                                // voxel is generated. If not, then a stone voxel is generated.
                                if(y >= (baseColumnHeight - 1) - (bottomColumnHeight / (topColumnHeight + 1)))
                                {
                                    this.Voxels[x, y, z] = new Dirt();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if(Random.Range(0.0f, 100.0f) >= baseColumnHeight - (bottomColumnHeight * 5.95f))
                                    {
                                        this.Voxels[x, y, z] = new Stone();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        this.Voxels[x, y, z] = new Dirt();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Generate a tree, if a randomly generated number is less than or equal
                        // to the tree generation chance.
                        if(
                            Random.Range(0.0f, 100.0f) <= this.TreeGenerationChance && 
                            finalNoiseResult <= this.SolidityThreshold + 0.25f
                        )
                        {
                            treeGenerated = true;
                            int trunkHeight = Random.Range(this.MinimumTrunkHeight, this.MaximumTrunkHeight);
                            int trunkTop = baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight + trunkHeight;
                            int leavesRadius = Random.Range(this.MinimumLeavesRadius, this.MaximumLeavesRadius);

                            // Generate the trunk of the tree, with a height that is similar to that of
                            // the generated tree height.
                            for(
                                int trunkY = baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight + 1;
                                trunkY < trunkTop;
                                trunkY++
                            )
                            {
                                if (this.IsValidCoordinate(x, trunkY, z))
                                {
                                    this.Voxels[x, trunkY, z] = new Wood();
                                }
                            }

                            // Generate the lower portion of the tree, with a larger width
                            // and depth than the top portions.
                            for(int leavesX = x - leavesRadius; leavesX <= x + leavesRadius; leavesX++)
                            {
                                for(int leavesY = trunkTop; leavesY <= trunkTop + leavesRadius; leavesY++)
                                {
                                    for(int leavesZ = z - leavesRadius; leavesZ <= z + leavesRadius; leavesZ++)
                                    {
                                        if(this.IsValidCoordinate(leavesX, leavesY, leavesZ))
                                        {
                                            if(
                                                this.Voxels[leavesX, leavesY, leavesZ] is Empty &&
                                                (leavesX != x - leavesRadius || leavesZ != z - leavesRadius) &&
                                                (leavesX != x + leavesRadius || leavesZ != z + leavesRadius) &&
                                                (leavesX != x + leavesRadius || leavesZ != z - leavesRadius) &&
                                                (leavesX != x - leavesRadius || leavesZ != z + leavesRadius)
                                            )
                                            {
                                                this.Voxels[leavesX, leavesY, leavesZ] = new Leaves();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            // Generate the upper portion of the tree, with a slightly smaller
                            // width and depth than the bottom portions.
                            for(int leavesX = x - (leavesRadius - 1); leavesX <= x + (leavesRadius - 1); leavesX++)
                            {
                                for(int leavesZ = z - (leavesRadius - 1); leavesZ <= z + (leavesRadius - 1); leavesZ++)
                                {
                                    if(this.IsValidCoordinate(leavesX, trunkTop + leavesRadius + 1, leavesZ))
                                    {
                                        if(this.Voxels[leavesX, trunkTop + leavesRadius + 1, leavesZ] is Empty)
                                        {
                                            this.Voxels[leavesX, trunkTop + leavesRadius + 1, leavesZ] = new Leaves();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // If a tree hasn't been generated, and the random condition succeeds, then generate
                        // a boulder.
                        if(Random.Range(0.0f, 100.0f) <= this.BoulderGenerationChance && !treeGenerated)
                        {
                            if(this.IsValidCoordinate(x, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight, z))
                            {
                                this.Voxels[x, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight, z] = new Stone();
                            }

                            if(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f) >= 0.45f)
                            {
                                if(this.IsValidCoordinate(x + 1, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight, z))
                                {
                                    this.Voxels[x + 1, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight, z] = new Stone();
                                }
                            }
                            if(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f) >= 0.45f)
                            {
                                if(this.IsValidCoordinate(x - 1, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight, z))
                                {
                                    this.Voxels[x - 1, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight, z] = new Stone();
                                }
                            }
                            if(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f) >= 0.45f)
                            {
                                if(this.IsValidCoordinate(x, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight, z + 1))
                                {
                                    this.Voxels[x, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight, z + 1] = new Stone();
                                }
                            }
                            if(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f) >= 0.45f)
                            {
                                if(this.IsValidCoordinate(x, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight, z - 1))
                                {
                                    this.Voxels[x, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight, z - 1] = new Stone();
                                }
                            }
                            if(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f) >= 0.65f)
                            {
                                if(this.IsValidCoordinate(x, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight + 1, z))
                                {
                                    this.Voxels[x, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight + 1, z] = new Stone();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Generate a cave, if cave generation has been specified. Otherwise, do nothing.
                        if(this.GenerateCaves)
                        {
                            bool generateCave = Random.Range(0.0f, 100.0f) <= this.CaveGenerationChance;

                            // Start a cave flood fill if a random number is less than or equal to
                            // the cave generation chance.
                            if(generateCave)
                            {
                                int caveY = (baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight) - Random.Range(0, 35);
                                int caveLength = Random.Range(this.MinimumCaveLength, this.MaximumCaveLength);

                                this.GenerateCave(x, caveY, z, caveLength);
                            }
                        }

                        // Set the player spawn position if the terrain generator's current position
                        // is greater than half the width & depth, if a spawn hasn't already been created,
                        // and if a tree hasn't been generated.
                        if(
                            x > (float)this.Width / 1.5f && 
                            z > (float)this.Depth / 1.5f && 
                            !playerSpawnCreated && 
                            !treeGenerated &&
                            this.UsesPlayer
                        )
                        {
                            this.PlayerSpawnPosition = new Vector3(x, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight + 2, z);
                            playerSpawnCreated = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(this.GenerateClouds)
            {
                // Perform one final iteration across the level's x and z axes, and add clouds. The
                // _Seed for the cloud noise operations is determined using the same world _Seed.
                for(int cloudX = 0; cloudX < this.Width; cloudX++)
                {
                    for(int cloudZ = 0; cloudZ < this.Depth; cloudZ++)
                    {
                        // Generate the first perlin noise result. This value is used as the first
                        // value in the noise lerp.
                        float perlinNoiseResultOne = Mathf.PerlinNoise(
                            (cloudX + this._Seed) / this.CloudFrequency,
                            (cloudZ + this._Seed) / this.CloudFrequency
                        );

                        // Generate the second perlin noise result. This value is used as the second
                        // value in the noise lerp.
                        float perlinNoiseResultTwo = Mathf.PerlinNoise(
                            (cloudX + this._Seed) / (this.CloudFrequency * 2),
                            (cloudZ + this._Seed) / (this.CloudFrequency * 2)
                        );

                        // Generate the third perlin noise result. This value is used as the "time" 
                        // value in the noise lerp.
                        float perlinNoiseResultThree = Mathf.PerlinNoise(
                            (cloudX + this._Seed) / (this.CloudFrequency * 3),
                            (cloudZ + this._Seed) / (this.CloudFrequency * 3)
                        );

                        // Generate the final noise result, which is a lerp between the first and second
                        // noise results based on the third noise result.
                        float finalPerlinNoiseResult = Mathf.Lerp(
                            perlinNoiseResultOne,
                            perlinNoiseResultTwo,
                            perlinNoiseResultThree
                        ) - UtilityFunctions.GenerateFalloffValue(
                            this.Width, 
                            cloudX, 
                            cloudZ, 
                            this.FalloffCurveAMultiplier, 
                            this.FalloffCurveBMultiplier
                        );

                        // Generate a cloud column if the perlin noise result meets the requirements
                        // for the solidity threshold.
                        if(finalPerlinNoiseResult >= this.CloudSolidityThreshold)
                        {
                            for(int y = this.BaseCloudHeight - this.CloudThickness; y < this.BaseCloudHeight + this.CloudThickness; y++)
                            {
                                if(this.Voxels[cloudX, y, cloudZ] is Empty)
                                {
                                    this.Voxels[cloudX, y, cloudZ] = new Cloud();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update is called once per frame.
        /// </summary>
        public void Update()
        {
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha1))
            {
                this.SetVoxel(new Stone(), 16, 16, 16);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function is responsible for creating a set of walls which surround the level
        /// and prevent the player from leaving the bounds of the level.
        /// </summary>
        public void GenerateLevelWalls()
        {
            GameObject wallsParent = new GameObject();
            wallsParent.name = "Walls";
            wallsParent.transform.position = Vector3.zero;

            GameObject northWall = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            northWall.name = "North Wall";
            northWall.transform.parent = wallsParent.transform;
            northWall.transform.position = new Vector3(this.Width / 2.0f, this.Height / 2.0f, this.Depth);
            northWall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(this.Width, this.Height + 3, 1.0f);
            northWall.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            northWall.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");

            GameObject southWall = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            southWall.name = "South Wall";
            southWall.transform.parent = wallsParent.transform;
            southWall.transform.position = new Vector3(this.Width / 2.0f, this.Height / 2.0f, 0);
            southWall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(this.Width, this.Height + 3, 1.0f);
            southWall.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            southWall.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");

            GameObject eastWall = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            eastWall.name = "East Wall";
            eastWall.transform.parent = wallsParent.transform;
            eastWall.transform.position = new Vector3(this.Width, this.Height / 2.0f, this.Depth / 2.0f);
            eastWall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, this.Height + 3, this.Depth);
            eastWall.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            eastWall.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");

            GameObject westWall = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            westWall.name = "West Wall";
            westWall.transform.parent = wallsParent.transform;
            westWall.transform.position = new Vector3(0, this.Height / 2.0f, this.Depth / 2.0f);
            westWall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, this.Height + 3, this.Depth);
            westWall.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            westWall.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");

            GameObject topWall = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            topWall.name = "Top Wall";
            topWall.transform.parent = wallsParent.transform;
            topWall.transform.position = new Vector3(this.Width / 2.0f, this.Height + 3, this.Depth / 2.0f);
            topWall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(this.Width, 1.0f, this.Depth);
            topWall.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            topWall.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start is called once.
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            // Set the width, height, and depth of the level to the settings
            // provided in the cross-scene object containing the level size
            // settings.
            if(this.UseLevelSizeStorage)
            {
                LevelSizeStorage levelSizeStorage = GameObject.Find("Level Size Storage").GetComponent<LevelSizeStorage>();
                this.Width = levelSizeStorage.Width;
                this.Height = levelSizeStorage.Height;
                this.Depth = levelSizeStorage.Depth;
            }

            // Initialize the voxel and chunk arrays to their specified sizes.
            this.Voxels = new Voxel[this.Width, this.Height, this.Depth];
            this.Chunks = new GameObject[this.Width / this.ChunkWidth, this.Height / this.ChunkHeight, this.Depth / this.ChunkDepth];

            // Set the values for the level's width, height, and depth in chunks.
            this.WidthInChunks = this.Width / this.ChunkWidth;
            this.HeightInChunks = this.Height / this.ChunkHeight;
            this.DepthInChunks = this.Depth / this.ChunkDepth;

            // Create a random _Seed for the RNG and perlin noise generators.
            if(this.UseUniqueSeed)
            {
                this._Seed = Random.Range(-1000000, 1000000);
                Random.seed = this._Seed;
            }
            else
            {
                unchecked
                {
                    this._Seed = (int)(((this.Width / 2.0f) + (this.Depth / 2.0f)) / 2.0f);
                }
            }

            // Generate the voxel, chunk and wall data.
            this.GenerateVoxelData();
            this.GenerateChunkData();
            this.GenerateLevelWalls();

            // Set the position of the player equal to the generated spawn position.
            if(this.UsesPlayer)
            {
                GameObject.Find("Player Object").transform.position = this.PlayerSpawnPosition;
                GameObject.Find("Player Object").GetComponent<PlayerController>().StartingPosition = this.PlayerSpawnPosition;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>This post is part two of a series based off [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/ShearOfDoom/Voxel-Islands/blob/master/Engine/Utilities/DynamicMesh.cs). Part one is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128634/voxel-islands-dynamic-mesh-generation).</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General**

To me your code contains waaaay to many `this`es. I'd do without them. Sometimes you even mix the conventions and use `this` as well as an *underscored* fields like: `this._Seed`.

**Level** class

It contains a lot of public fields that look like they were some constants but neither of them is marked as `const` or `readonly`.

There are lines that use magic numbers like:

```
Random.Range(0.0f, 100.0f) <= 20.0f
```

or

```
if(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f) >= 0.45f)
```

I assume they were simply overseen because you have already defined quite a few of them.

---

You are not using helper variables consequently. In the same `if` you define one

```
bool generateCave = Random.Range(0.0f, 100.0f) <= this.CaveGenerationChance;

// Start a cave flood fill if a random number is less than or equal to
// the cave generation chance.
if(generateCave)
{
    int caveY = (baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight) - Random.Range(0, 35);
    int caveLength = Random.Range(this.MinimumCaveLength, this.MaximumCaveLength);

    this.GenerateCave(x, caveY, z, caveLength);
}
```

and a few lines later you chose a *huge* `if`

```
// Set the player spawn position if the terrain generator's current position
// is greater than half the width & depth, if a spawn hasn't already been created,
// and if a tree hasn't been generated.
if(
    x > (float)this.Width / 1.5f && 
    z > (float)this.Depth / 1.5f && 
    !playerSpawnCreated && 
    !treeGenerated &&
    this.UsesPlayer
)
{
    this.PlayerSpawnPosition = new Vector3(x, baseColumnHeight + topColumnHeight + 2, z);
    playerSpawnCreated = true;
}
```

---

The `GenerateVoxelData` method is a good candidate for refactoring. It's 400 lines long. Almost each `if` inside the `for-loop` could be a separate method for generating something and the last `if` behind it for generating clouds definitely.

They not only should have their own methods but also go into another class like `Object/ModelGenerator` or something like that followed by other *generate* routines like `GenerateLevelWalls` that luckily already has its own function ;-)

---

**Voxel** class

You pass a `DynamicMesh` data to various methods of the voxel class but you don't store it anywhere.

I think it would be a better idea to move dynamic mesh related properties and methods to the `DynamicMesh` and override its methods in different dynamic meshes if necessary rather then the `Voxel`'s:

```
public class DynamicMesh
{       
    public Vector3 HalvedOffset { get; set; }

    // ... other properties and methods

    public virtual DynamicMesh CreateNorthFace(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        AddVertex(new Vector3(x + HalvedOffset.x, y - HalvedOffset.y, z + HalvedOffset.z), Offset, IsCollideable);
        AddVertex(new Vector3(x + HalvedOffset.x, y + HalvedOffset.y, z + HalvedOffset.z), Offset, IsCollideable);
        AddVertex(new Vector3(x - HalvedOffset.x, y + HalvedOffset.y, z + HalvedOffset.z), Offset, IsCollideable);
        AddVertex(new Vector3(x - HalvedOffset.x, y - HalvedOffset.y, z + HalvedOffset.z), Offset, IsCollideable);
        AddQuad(IsCollideable);
        AddUVs(GenerateUVs(VoxelFaceDirection.North));
        return this;
    }
}
```

The voxel could recieve a dynamic mesh via its constructor.

**Enums**

Both enums should be moved to their own files because they are public already. It would be fine to place them inside a class if they were private. Now if you wanted to use them somewhere else you need to write `Voxel.VoxelFaceDirection` which is an unnecessary repetition. You could remove the voxel prefix but then another problem arises that you cannot have a property with the same name inside the voxel class. That's why I prefer to put them in separate files.